# Something with my queue is just not working, when I try to add a song to queue it's just skipping the current song

Tags: queue, bots, discord.js

I followed an old video that shows how to create music bot,  I fixed most problems, but the part of the queue I couldn't fix.

```
switch (args[0]) {
  case 'play':
    function play(connection, message) {
      var server = servers[message.guild.id];

      server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], { filter: "audio" }));
      message.reply("have a good listening sir!")


      server.queue.shift();

      server.dispatcher.on("end", function () {
        if (server.queue[0]){
          play(connection, message);

        } else {

        connection.disconnect();   

        }
      });

    }


    if (!args[1]) {
      message.channel.send("you need to provide a link! sir");
      return;
    }

    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.channel.send("you must be in a channel to play the bot sir!);
      return;
    }

    if (!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
      queue: []
    }

    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

    server.queue.push(args[1]);

    if (!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection) {
      play(connection, message);
    })

    break;

  case 'skip':
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];
    if (server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
    message.channel.send("Skipping the song sir!")

    break;

  case 'leave':
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];
    if (message.guild.voiceConnection) {
      }

      server.dispatcher.end();
      message.channel.send('leaving the voice channel sir have a great day! :wave_tone1: ')
      console.log('stopped the queue')
    }

  if (message.guild.connection)message.guild.voiceConnection.disconnect();
```

There are no errors it is just skipping to the next song, I would appreciate the help. I have tried anything and nothing works.
Sorry if my code is bad I am new to coding.

Note:**I am using ytdl-core**